# Why using 'nil' after releasing objects

Tags: objective-c, release

Sometimes i saw this type of codeing in objective-c. Why set _imageView to nil after releasing.

```
 - (void)dealloc {
    [_imageView release];
    _imageView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to ensure that you don't try to reuse the object that you've just released.

By setting it to `nil`, you ensure that any future messages to it will be tossed away (the behaviour for the standard `nil` object) rather than causing a problem.

Comment: On a sidenote, its usually not needed to set the ivar to nil in the `dealloc` method. Unless one does hacky stuff with the superclasses ivars.

Answer (score 2):

Just because it's safe practice.

In dealloc it doesn't really make much sense unless you're using threads, but otherwise it's always good to do it every time you're assigning nil to an object (unless it's a property).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, it's not necessary in dealloc. However, when releasing an object in any other method the pointer will still remain, but the object it's pointing to will exist no more, causing a crash when sending a message to it.

By setting the pointer to nil you are sure that any message sent to it will simply be ignored instead of crashing your application (or causing weird behaviour).